# how can I create a list of receipts from database in javafx?

Tags: javafx, receipt

I have two database table,

```
"product"  table has those fields--> prID, transactionID, itemName, itemQuantity, itemPrice.

"payment"  table has those fields--> pyID, paymentID, paymentType, paymentAmount, itemPrice.
```

> transactionID and paymentID are the same.

now, I like to create list of receipts for the same day.
What is your suggestion to do that?
I have to use two table, and add some extra data and it needs to span inside the container (tabPane).
here is the pic of something i am trying to do.[image: receipts_sample]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using TilePane and putting GridPane in this TilePane did the job. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I used TilePane and put the GridPane in this TilePane. 
I also created Labels and spanned these labels inside GridPane.
So far I havent done the database fetching for this project but what I was looking for is this idea.
Thanks everyone who showed an interest in this subject.